# How to get total number of print pages in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am working on one project where i need to calculate total number of pages of excel file.**(on Linux server)**

I have google a lot but there is no such thing in **PHPExcel** available.
So finally here to get any idea from you guys.

Comment: You can't, because that's not information stored anywhere in the file; number of pages in print format is totally dependent on such things as paper size, margins, font sizes, row heights, etc.... you might be able to calculate it, but PHPExcel itself doesn't provide any functionality for anything that complex and ambiguous... the best suggestion I can make is save to pdf and then parse the pdf to count the pages

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you mean number of sheets, and you mean PHPExcel (not PDFExcel) you can get it `$nrOfSheets = $excelObj->getSheetCount();`

Comment: thanks PDFExcel was typo ...
But sir i need total number of pages not sheets.